John Major's equality and John Major's reflexivity
The following lemma is immediate by reflexivity:
Lemma eq_rect_eq_refl_eq (A : Type) (x : A) (P : A -> Type) (v : P x) (y : A) :
@eq_rect A x P v x eq_refl = v.
Proof. exact (@eq_refl (P x) (@eq_rect A x P v x (@eq_refl A x))). Qed.

How can I prove a similar lemma for John Major's Equality?
Lemma JMeq_rect_JMeq_refl_eq (A : Type) (x : A) (P : A -> Type) (v : P x) (y : A) :
@JMeq_rect A x P v x JMeq_refl = v.

My attempt to construct a similar proof fails:
Proof. Fail exact (@eq_refl (P x) (@JMeq_rect A x P v x (@JMeq_refl A x))). Abort. 

This produces the following error:
The term "eq_refl" has type
 "JMeq_rect P v JMeq_refl = JMeq_rect P v JMeq_refl"
while it is expected to have type "JMeq_rect P v JMeq_refl = v".

A weaker lemma fails too:
Lemma JMeq_rect_JMeq_refl_JMeq
  (A : Type) (x : A) (P : A -> Type) (v : P x) (y : A) :
JMeq (@JMeq_rect A x P v x JMeq_refl) v.
Proof. Fail exact (@JMeq_refl (P x) (@JMeq_rect A x P v x (@JMeq_refl A x))). Abort.

This produces the following error:
The term "JMeq_refl" has type
 "JMeq (JMeq_rect P v JMeq_refl) (JMeq_rect P v JMeq_refl)"
while it is expected to have type "JMeq (JMeq_rect P v JMeq_refl) v".

What is the correct approach to prove those lemmas ? Can classical logic help? Or is there a fundamental reason why such lemmas cannot be proven? Could they be safely added as axioms?

Note that this has nothing to do with classical logic whatsoever.

As far as I can tell, this is not possible with the definitions from the standard library.
The JMeq_rect theorem is Qed-terminated, so it behaves as an axiom. In particular, you cannot compute with it in any way. Furthermore, I believe that there is no way to prove your property without some knowledge of the body of JMeq_rect since it could behave in a non-uniform way when P y is not a h-proposition.
Note that even if the body was exposed you would likely run into trouble since JMeq_rect ultimately depends on an axiom that boils down to some variant of UIP. I did not check what the whole dependency chain looks like exactly but one has to be careful how UIP is stated in order for your original theorem to be proved.

I don't think the lemma requires any axioms; it is just the computation rule for JMeq and should be part of the type. In Agda --without-K it is just refl: https://gist.github.com/ncfavier/7ae26ab98e247427305bef20bfb0938e

AFAICT those Qeds should be changed to Defineds; surely there's no reason for a type's eliminator to be opaque?

The type theory of Coq does not validate the K rule, so it must be added as an axiom. This is Eqdep.eq_rect_eq : forall (U:Type) (p:U) (Q:U -> Type) (x:Q p) (h:p = p), x = eq_rect p Q x p h. Axioms are inert and do not compute, although this can be hacked around using e.g. rewrite rules.

I know, I'm saying you don't need K for this! (Unless I've missed something)

You definitely need it, because JMeq_rect is literally equivalent to K. Note that despite the name, JMeq_rect is not the induction principle associated to the JMeq type. In this case, the automatic generation of the induction principle has been specifically deactivated, and the name of the principle has been bound instead to a stronger variant depending on K.

Ah, yes, you're right. I didn't look at the type of JMeq_rect carefully enough...
